# Check EOF while looping through file

Tags: perl, eof

I am reading file `15inv.txt` line by line. I get the "item number" from each line and then open another file `active.txt` and search for a matching item number.

If I find a match, I want to print it out to `results.txt` with "matched" attached. If I get to the end of the file and do not find it print out "No match EOF reached".

I am trying to find whether the item number in `15inv.txt` is in `active.txt`.

The `15inv.txt` file looks like this. The file can have multiple item numbers.

```
1 5,I413858,O313071 ,2015-5-11 12:01:01,10033,WHITE HOUSE FURNITURE                   ,FAIRFIELD           ,NJ,29562,1,460,460
```

The `active.txt` file has the item number in it and it only shows up once.

```
30-18
30-46
26817
```

Where am I going wrong in my code?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$inv = '15inv.txt';
open INV, "<$inv" or die "Unable to open the file\n";

$inv_out = '15inv-OBS.csv';
open INVOUT, ">$inv_out" or die "Unable to open the file\n";

$count = 0;
print INVOUT "Item #, Qty, Cost, Ext Cost, Status \n";

while ( <INV> ) {

    $inv_line = $_;
    chomp($inv_line);
    $count++;

    ($inv_rep, $inv_invoice, $inv_order, $inv_date, $inv_account, $inv_name, $inv_city, $inv_state, $inv_item, $inv_qty, $inv_cost, $inv_ecost)  = split(/,/, $inv_line);

    $inv_item =~ s/\s+//;  # remove spaces

    $active = 'active.txt'; # active items
    open ACTIVE, "<$active" or die "Unable to open the file\n";

    while ( <ACTIVE> ) {

        $the_active = $_;
        chomp($the_active);

        $active_item = substr($the_active, 0,10);

        $active_item =~ s/\s+//;
        next if ( $inv_item ne $active_item );

        if ( $inv_item eq $active_item ) {
            print INVOUT "$inv_item, $inv_qty, $inv_cost,$inv_ecost,IN \n";
            next;
        } # end of if 

    } # end of ACTIVE while loop

    print INVOUT "$inv_item, $inv_qty, $inv_cost,$inv_ecost, EOF \n";

} # end of INV while loop

print "Done!!! \n";

close FILE;
close INV;
close INVOUT;

exit;
```

Comment: 1) So what do you actually get? 2) at a glance there are too many `next`s 3) Please indent that code. //  You re-read the other file for _every line_ of the `15inv.txt`! That's very inefficient, and prohibitively so for large files. Instead, populate a hash with data of interest from `15inv.txt` -- for each `$active_item` make it a key with a value `1`. Then go _once_ through the other file, checking all items you need.

Comment: I am not familiar with hashes, My out put is duplicated, after it matches my if statement ( $inv_item eq $active_item ) it prints out to my file and then again on the last print statement line for EOF.  The first next is looping through the active file trying to match the item numbers, then second next is looping back to top of file because the 15inv file an multiple entries, the third next if when it never finds the item number

Comment: Your last line seems to print unconditionally, so it will of course print.  The posted code is broken, with an extra `}` and seemingly meaningless statement after an unconditional `next`.  _Can you please fix the post_ so to show what you _are_ running?  You can hit the "edit" (gray, shaded) link right under the post.

Comment: Yes 26817 1 108 108 IN 
26817 1 108 108  EOF 
29301 3 185 555  EOF 
26524 1 805 805  EOF 
26823 2 180 360  EOF 
R061-20 1 1585 1585  EOF 
26850 1 208 208  EOF 
26503 1 230 230  EOF

Comment: This looks almost like perl4 code (except I don't think perl4 had `chomp` yet). You should always start with `use strict; use warnings;` (and `perl -w` has been mostly obsolete since 2000).

Comment: it is perl v5.18.2

Comment: I have updated the code and matched up the "}" did not find any extras.

Comment: @Sandwick Yes, which is why you should start every Perl file with `use strict; use warnings;` and not use `-w` anymore. Next steps would be: Use 3-argument `open`, use lexical variables instead of globals, use lexical variables instead of bareword filehandles, properly indent your code, mention the filename and error reason (`$!`) in your error messages, etc.

Comment: You split the lines from `15inv.txt` into twelve variables, but the sample of your data has only six fields. How is that supposed to work?  Are there always just  three lines in `active.txt`? Do all three contain item numbers?

Comment: @Sandwick: I have tidied your Perl code so that I could understand it properly. It is essential that you do this for yourself in future, especially before asking for help to fix it. Comments that mark the end of code blocks are generally a sign that your program needs to be organised better: now that it's indented it's easy to see which closing brace belongs to which opening brace. As **melpomene** has said, Perl v5.8 was released sixteen years ago, and best practice has been to `use strict` and `use warnings` and lexical file handles ever since. You should find a more modern Perl tutorial.

Comment: Once opened where do you close ACTIVE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking about how to print something if you don't find it in the other file. Typically I use a flag variable for this. It's false until you find the thing. If it's still false when you've gone through the whole file, you didn't find it:

```
my $look_for = ...;
my $found = 0;

while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    $_ eq $look_for ? $found = 1 : next;
    ...
    }

unless( $found ) {
    print "Not found!";
    }
```

One way to detect these problems is to reduce your program to the smallest thing that can show the problem (rather than the entire working script). Try it in the small then build on that.